# Sample with replacement from existing array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix A with shape 1.6M rows and 400 columns.

One of the columns in A (call it the *output* column) has binary values (0,1) with a **predominance** of 0's.

I want to create a new matrix B (same shape as A) by sampling rows in A with replacement such, that the distribution of 0's & 1's in the *output* column in B becomes **50/50**.

**What is the efficient way to do this using python/numpy?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by:

1. Creating a list of all rows with `0` in the "output column" (called `outputZeros`), and a list of all rows with `1` in the output column (called `outputOnes`); then,
2. Sampling with replacement from `outputZeros` and `outputOnes` 1.6M times.

Here's a small example. It's not clear to me if you want the rows in `B` to be in any particular order, so here they first include `0`s, then include `1`s.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np, random
In [2]: A = np.random.rand(10, 2)
In [3]: A
In [4]: A[:7, 1] = 0
In [5]: A[7:, 1] = 1
In [6]: A
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.70126052,  0.        ],
       [ 0.51161067,  0.        ],
       [ 0.76511966,  0.        ],
       [ 0.91257144,  0.        ],
       [ 0.97024895,  0.        ],
       [ 0.55817776,  0.        ],
       [ 0.55963466,  0.        ],
       [ 0.6318139 ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.90176108,  1.        ],
       [ 0.76033151,  1.        ]])
In [7]: outputZeros = np.where(A[:, 1] == 0)[0]
In [8]: outputZeros
Out[8]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
In [9]: outputOnes
Out[9]: array([7, 8, 9])
In [10]: outputOnes = np.where(A[:, 1] == 1)[0]
In [11]: B = np.zeros((10, 2))
In [12]: for i in range(10):
    if i < 5:
        B[i,  :] = A[random.choice(outputZeros), :]
    else:
        B[i, :] = A[random.choice(outputOnes), :]
   ....:         
In [13]: B
Out[13]: 
array([[ 0.97024895,  0.        ],
       [ 0.97024895,  0.        ],
       [ 0.76511966,  0.        ],
       [ 0.76511966,  0.        ],
       [ 0.51161067,  0.        ],
       [ 0.90176108,  1.        ],
       [ 0.76033151,  1.        ],
       [ 0.6318139 ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.6318139 ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.76033151,  1.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new 1D numpy array filled with values from [numpy.random.random_integers(low, high=None, size=None)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_integers.html#numpy.random.random_integers) and swap that new array with the old one.

Comment: I wouldn't actually set `high=None`, but otherwise this is a sensible answer.

Comment: @edouard: Not sure if I understand your approach - I don't want random entries in the output column in B, I want it to be what it was in its position in A.